# Which library should I use for editable grid in HTML?

Tags: html

I am creating a simple web application.

Web application server: Tomcat.
DB application server: MYSQL.

In one page I want to manipulate table (adding/editing/deleting).

Which FrameWork/library should I use?

P.s. I tried EditableGrid (http://www.editablegrid.net/en), but there some limitations like:

- I don't know how to hide some cols;
- I can delete only one column per action. ( I want to select and delete many).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [slickgrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki) ?
Example here: [link](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example3-editing.html)